# Serve private, user-uploaded media from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, access-control

I'm evaluating using GCP for my new project, however, I'm still trying to figure out how to implement the following feature and what kind of costs it will have.

## TL;DR

What's the best strategy to serve user-uploaded media from GCP while giving users *full control* on who will be able to access them?

## Feature Description

As an User, I want to upload some kind of media (eg: image, videos, etc...) in a private and secure way.
The media must be visible by me and by a specific subgroup of users to which I've granted access to.
Anybody else must not be able to access the media, even if he obtained the URL.

The media content would then be displayed on the website.

## Dilemma

I would like to use Cloud Storage to store all the media, however, I'm struggling to find a suitable solution for the authorization part.

As far as I can tell, features related to "Access Control" are mostly tailored at Project and Organisational level.

The closest feature so far are Signed URLs, but this doesn't satisfy the requirement of not being able to access it even if you have the URL, even though it expires soon after and perhaps it could be a good compromise.
Another problem with this approach is that the media cannot be cached at the browser level, which could save quite some bandwidth in the long run...

## Expensive Solution?

One solution that came to my mind, is that I could serve it through a GCE instance by putting an App there that validate a user, probably through a JWT, and then stream it back while using the appropriate cache headers.

This should satisfy all requirements, but I'm afraid about egress costs skyrocketing :(

---

Thank you to whoever will help!

Comment: You get charged the same egress price whether it's from GCE or GCS though?

Comment: @Hitobat you're right, now that I double check, traffic between CE and Storage should be free for same region, so the only egress cost is the one for the CE, which is indeed the same as Storage! Thanks for point it out :)

Comment: Hello, I am at the same position you were here. What did you do at the end? Thank you in advance and regards

Comment: @JavierGuzmán sadly the project is dead, but we did access rights at app level and then stream the file back

Answer (score 2):

Signed URLs are the solution you want.

Create a service account that represents your application. When a user of your application wants to upload an object, vend them a signed URL for performing the upload. The new object will be readable only by your service account (and other members of your project).

When a user wants to view an object, perform whatever checks you like and then vend them a signed URL for reading the object. Set a short expiration time if you are worried about the URLs being shared.

I would not advise the GCE-based approach unless you get some additional benefit out of it. I don't see how it adds any additional security to serve the data directly instead of via a signed URL.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think media can be correctly cached at browser level given that the URL change due to signature and expiration; this could save a good amount of traffic for commonly used media, like user profile images, etc...
It also turns out that price for doing so should be the same, so I'm currently leaning towards that solution. Can you see any other reason to prefer Signed URLs?